# Python3 for loop acting un-expectedly

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I was making a program when I came across this:

```
File "intcrypt.py", line 11
    if(item == 9):
             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Im really confused as to how this is possible? It seems fine to me, I've wrote a program like this many times and they all ran smoothly. For all logic I have im pretty darn sure that the indenting seems correct. What could be the problem?

this is my code:

```
num = 23983209

mylist = list(map(int,str(num)))

anotherlist = []

for item in mylist:

    item += 0

    if(item == 9):

        print("Item == 9!")

    anotherlist.append(item)

print(anotherlist)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if you have mixed spaces and tabs.  Also you probably mean `anotherlist.append(item)`.  Cutting and pasting the code above with the correction mentioned made the code work, so the code above doesn't reproduce the indentation error.

Comment: Thanks! all good

Answer (score 0):

If I copy paste the program into this [interpret](https://repl.it/languages/python3), there is no indetation error. However, there is error in appending to the list. It should be `anotherlist.append(item)`

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
    anotherlist.append(item)
```

not

```
    item.append(anotherist)
```

correct code

```
num = 23983209

mylist = list(map(int,str(num)))

print mylist
anotherlist = []

for item in mylist:

    item += 0

    if(item == 9):

        print("Item == 9!")

    anotherlist.append(item) #problem in this line

print(anotherlist)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and the error mentioned doesn't produce the error in the question.

Comment: That wasn't the problem, but I did fix that code. Thanks!